# Django + Vue. Can't connect params

Tags: python, django, api, vue.js, django-rest-framework

So, the problem is that i can't connect Django REST with Vue. When I'm calling API from Client it says:

```
Not Found: /api/private/
[16/Sep/2018 13:18:59] "GET /api/private/?city=London HTTP/1.1" 404 2129
```

This is my code:

Vue function

```
callWeather () {
      const url = `${API_URL}/api/private/`
      return axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${AuthService.getAuthToken()}`
        },
        params: {
          'city': 'London'
        }
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.message = response.data || ''
      })
    }
```

Django api url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/public/', views.public),
    url(r'^api/private/(?P<city>\w+)/$', views.private)
]
```

Django private func:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def private(request, city):
    return HttpResponse("City is: {}.".format(city))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mismatch between your `axios.get`, and the `private` view. In your `axios.get` you pass data through the GET parameters (the querystring). While in your URL patterns, you write the `city` parameter as a part of the URL.

## Using the *querystring* (`GET` parameters)

You can for example change the `urlpatterns` to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/public/', views.public),
    url(r'^api/private/$', views.private)
]
```

In the view, you then can obtain the value associated with the `city` through:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def private(request):
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    return HttpResponse("City is: {}.".format(city))
```

In case the `city` parameter is not in the querystring, here `city` will be `None`, so perhaps you want to check on that.

## Using the URL

We can also encode the parameter in the URL, in that case you will need to do some formatting such that the `url` looks like:

```
callWeather () {
      const url = '${API_URL}/api/private/London/'
      return axios.get(url, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ${AuthService.getAuthToken()}'
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        this.message = response.data || ''
      })
    }
```